# Redirect specific page in Wordpress for first time visit

Tags: functions, redirect, template-redirect

I tried the following to redirect one page on the first visit:

```
function check_for_redirect() {
    if( is_page( 8219 ) )
    $days_to_expire = 30;

    if (!is_admin() && !isset($_COOKIE['already_visited'])) {
        setcookie('already_visited', true, time() + 86400 * $days_to_expire);
        wp_redirect('/welkom', 302); //change the URL and status to whatever you want
        exit;
    }
}
add_action('init', 'check_for_redirect');
```

I get a Redirect loop if i use this one. How to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

I would always hook it to `template_redirect`. Something like this:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'custom_check_for_redirect' );

function custom_check_for_redirect(){
  global $wp_query; # It could work without this too!
  
  if( is_page( 8219 ) )
    $days_to_expire = 30;

    if (!is_admin() && !isset($_COOKIE['already_visited'])) {
        setcookie('already_visited', true, time() + 86400 * $days_to_expire);
        wp_redirect(home_url('/welkom'), 302);
        exit;
    };

};
```

Comment: I'd add the recommendation that instead of hardcoding the ID you'd set up an option in your theme where you could assign a page in case you ever change which page you want it to be.  As a dev it's easy for you but it's good practice to try and build things so non-development users can work with as many aspects as possible.  You could even set the days to expire as an option, etc.

Comment: @TonyDjukic Yes that's right! Absolutely.